# How to define blog relation database structure in NoSQL

Tags: database, nosql

In relation database,
I have data model: user, post, comment to story, voting to story.

```
user:
id,
username
pass
email

post:
user_id
title
body
etc...

comment:
id
user_id
post_id
body
date
etc....


vote:
id
user_id
post_id
date
```

what is normal way to define in NoSQL like MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can research the best practice here

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/
2. http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/